# Why is my variable is unbound in one inner function but not the other?

Tags: python

In the code below, why does the first version of `say` work but the second version throws "local variable 'running_high' referenced before assignment"?

```
def announce_highest(who, last_score=0, running_high=0):
    
    assert who == 0 or who == 1, 'The who argument should indicate a player.'
    ''' this one works
    def say(*scores):
        assert len(scores) == 2
        gain = scores[who] - last_score 
        if gain > running_high:
            print(gain, "point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player", who)
            return announce_highest(who, scores[who], gain)
        return announce_highest(who, scores[who], running_high)
    return say
    '''
    # this one errors "local variable 'running_high' referenced 
    # before assignment"
    def say(*scores): 
        gain = scores[who] - last_score
        if gain > running_high:
            running_high = scores[who]-last_score            
            print(gain,"point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player",who) 
            return announce_highest(who, scores[who], gain)   
        return announce_highest(who,scores[who],running_high)
    return say
```

Comment: `running_high` is not initialized before the loop, so how should the `if gain > running_high:` use this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one key difference between your two solutions which is causing them to behave differently: In the second solution, you assign a value to `running_high` on the third line:

```py
    def say(*scores): 
        gain = scores[who] - last_score
        if gain > running_high:
            # here
            running_high = scores[who]-last_score
```

Python [variable scoping](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) is a little bit different than other languages. The order of name resolution is as follows:

1. Local (function) scope. There is no [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)) scope in python, in contrast to many other languages, so e.g. the following code is valid:

   ```
    if True:
        foo = "foo"
    else:
        foo = "bar"
    print(foo)
   ```

   Even though `foo` is defined inside either the `if` block or the `else` block, it can be used outside of those blocks because it's still in the local scope.
2. Enclosing (nonlocal) scope. Inside `say`, `running_high` is in this scope, because it is a parameter to `announce_highest`, the *enclosing* function.
3. Global (module) scope. The top-most scope accessible to the programmer. If you define something in a script outside of a function, it's in the global scope.
4. Built-in scope. This contains all of python's [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), [keywords](https://realpython.com/python-keywords/), etc.

Coming back to the question at hand, when you make an assignment to `running_high` in your second solution, you redefine it in the local scope. This is known as [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). We say the function-local `running_high` defined in `say` *shadows* the enclosing function `running_high` defined as a parameter of `announce_highest`.

However, the assignment on line 3 is not the first thing you do with your new local variable. On line 2, you try to use it in a comparison (`if gain > running_high:`). The interpreter hasn't yet seen `running_high` at this point in the local scope and as such has no value for it, hence the error.

The [solution](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) to this is to use the special keywords `global` and `nonlocal` to tell the interpreter that `running_high` is not a local variable. In this specific case, `running_high` is in the enclosing or nonlocal scope, so you need to rewrite your second solution as follows:

```py
    def say(*scores): 
        nonlocal running_high
        ...
```

To recap, here is your first solution:

```py
    def say(*scores):
        assert len(scores) == 2
        gain = scores[who] - last_score 
        # running_high isn't in the local scope, so the interpreter
        # automatically looks for it in the enclosing scope. it exists
        # as a parameter of announce_highest, so this is valid code
        if gain > running_high:
            print(gain, "point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player", who)
            return announce_highest(who, scores[who], gain)
        return announce_highest(who, scores[who], running_high)
```

And here is the second:

```py
    def say(*scores): 
        gain = scores[who] - last_score
        if gain > running_high:
            # you didn't tell the interpreter where to look for the name
            # running_high, so it assumes you want to create a new local
            # variable. however, you tried to access running_high on the
            # previous line before it had a value, hence the error
            running_high = scores[who]-last_score            
            print(gain,"point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player",who) 
            return announce_highest(who, scores[who], gain)   
        return announce_highest(who,scores[who],running_high)
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I missed the ```announce_highest``` function which takes "running_high" as a parameter. I'm just confused why the first solution can work but the second one doesn't. I understand and appreciate your explanation :)

Comment: The reason your first solution works is because it doesn't assign to `running_high`, and therefore the `running_high` from the enclosing scope (`announce_highest`) is used. I realize now that that's really your question, so I'm going to rework my answer to explain why one solution works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again:)! I assume that since ```running_high``` is passed to ```announce_highest```  and ```say``` is inside of ```announce_highest```the interpreter will find it in the ```announce_highest``` frame, which is wrong.

Comment: Happy to help. If you believe this has sufficiently answered your question, please accept it using the check mark button on the upper left-hand side of the answer. That makes it easy for anyone else with the same question to tell what helped you the most.